# Understanding Firebase Audiences Membership Duration

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I am a bit new to firebase and I have of course many questions about it. In particular I would like to understand firebase membership duration better. I know just from the documentation that firebase checks periodically to see if a user still qualifies to an audience but if a user still meets the requirements but is over the membership duration then they are excluded.

1. Does this mean they will never be able to qualify again for the audience?
2. If I make an audience where a user joins by triggering an event with in one day (I do this by setting even count greater than 0 within one day) but the membership duration is 30 days. Does the number of users in my audience tell me all the users who meet the requirements and have continued to meet the requirements in a 30 day period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A user can rejoin an audience if they meet the conditions for that audience again.
2. What you're describing is known as the 30-day-active user count (or MAU for monthly active users). It is the number of users that we active in a certain 30-day time interval. Since you say they join the audience by one event, they only need to trigger the event once in that period to be considered part of the audience.